# Tableau Changing Data When a Connection is Made

Tags: excel, tableau-api

I'm trying to analyze a set of data across 3 excel tables in Tableau.
When I just use 1 table (transactions) the data is correct and works normally, however when I make a connection, it seems like Tableau takes the originally correct data and deletes/duplicated entries seemingly at random (I've looked for patterns to see what the problem is, can't find them).

Here are some screenshots to illustrate the problem. I'm using inner joins. The tables I'm joining should have no impact on the data that I'm currently talking about.

This is a large data set (> 400,000 rows)

Correct Data:
[From Excel, ordered by date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gltNn.png)

Tableau's Data Set (notice the missing entries (PK field) and incorrect order despite order by date)

[Looking at PK and Distribution Amount](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30tUk.png)

This is my first time using stackexchange so I apologize if I breached any kind of etiquette requirements! Any suggestions as to how to correct the data set tableau is detecting would be extremely helpful!

EDIT: Also, going deeper into the bad data it seems as though even when sorted chronologically the data in tableau is not in the correct order

Comment: The first thing I would check is whether you are filtering out data because of your inner joins. The order of rows in the query results set is immaterial.

Comment: Could you please share a diagram of the relationship between tables?

Comment: It isn't connecting that causes the issues: it is the way you *join* the tables together. Joins are complicated and often cause issues if you don't set them up right. I'd experiment with alternative ways of specifying the joins between tables. Also, make sure to use standard date formats (eg ISO yyyy-mm-dd rather than the illogical US format) and make sure Tableau has interpreted them correctly as dates and not strings or numbers.